# Socket.IO Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, web-applications, npm

To start I'm not a coding expert so excuse me if this was a newbie question.
I have installed a nodejs app into my VPS (digital ocean), after uploading everything (both server side and client side) seem to be running but I'm having an issue.

The dependencies are managed using bower so installed everything in the root directory of Apache server. As I use the "Inspect Element" in my browser to see 
the console I get a first error of:

```
http://104.131.66.68/manager/bower_components/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min.js Failed to load resource: 
the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I checked the bower_components folder in my server and the folder socket.io-client exists! But when I checked through my browser to see the source files it is not there! Other dependencies are available.

These are the errors that appear, the socket.io error at the top most i suspect the reset are due to the same problem and lastly is the API Key (i intend to handle that after this).

[image]

your help is highly appreciated!!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` use this to serve the socket.io client. If it does not work, you are having something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer. i have tried it but the error is still the same just changed http://104.131.66.68/socket.io/socket.io.js

Comment: This should surely mean you are not doing something wright in your code. Visit socket.io website and follow the way to create a socket server with express.